# "iTunes could not be started" error in VS after reinstalling iTunes

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, itunes, visual-studio-cordova

I reinstalled iTunes for some reason, after that, following error apears in VS:

[image]

Tried to restart pc and reconnect the iphone.

Comment: I don't post it as an answer because it doesn't solve the error, but to anyone who just need to install the compiled *.ipa file on yor iOS - you can double click it under the folder <project_dir>\bin\iOS\<Release\Debug>\<appname>.ipa

Comment: I get this issue along with msg about COM components in VS 2017 community on win10 - my guess is that VS is looking to communicate with full iTunes (desktop version) which I cannot find online anywhere - only the MS store version, which I guess is a Modern UI app - and I guess has standard restrictions on what it can do - and probably can't help with debugging your app on device through VS ! Guessing this is all part of Apple's scheme to force us to buy overprices Mac's just to dev for iOS when MS could do it all much better for us if given the chance ;)

Comment: I ended up following this advice https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/31 from @unboxed and using xcode on mac to run the app... well done Apple - you've won this one you overpriced chromed plonkers !!! ha

Answer (score 3):

If your Visual Studio is running in the Admin mode (if you started it by "Run as Administrator"), then you need to run iTunes also in the Admin mode (Find the iTunes icon -> Right Click -> Run as Administrator). .